# Is it "that's the same story, know?" or "that's the same story, no?"

Tags: question-tags

I am getting quite confused by:

1. That's also the same story, know?
2. That's also the same story, no?

Which is correct formation?  This is very confusing to me.

Comment: Please clarify your question. It is not at all clear wht you're asking.

Comment: Using ' no?' at the end of a sentence in place of 'isn't it?' or its equivalent sounds all wrong to me. It makes sense, but it sounds like a non-English idiom translated into English.
Or is that just me? ;)

Comment: I guess user4777 is being confused from the fact that, hearing the sentence (or similar sentences), he is not able to understand if the speaker is saying _know_, or _no_. In fact, the American pronunciation reported by the NOAD is the same for both the words: /nəʊ/.

Comment: @gpr: to my ear, it’s a regional thing — a fairly strong marker of certain dialects.  Unfortunately I’m not honestly sure which ones, and I have no documentation for this — but it certainly has a strong feeling of “this is unusual to me, but for the people who use it, very common”.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is *no?*, not *know?*. As mentioned in Justin Morgan's answer, *no?* is used instead of *isn't it?* which one would expect as a tag on the end of this sentence to make it a question (due to the negative form of the *be* verb which has been shortened in this sentence here: *that's*).

Answer (score 2):

Ending a sentence in `, no?` is the same thing as `, isn't it?` or `, don't you think?`  But from your examples, neither one is correct because you are missing a *verb*.

`That is also the same story, no?`

Answer (score 2):

Just to nuance the two existing answers, what you might be thinking of is this:

> That's the same story, you know?

Comment: This construction is generally phrased as a statement, not a question. If I wanted to *ask* whether the person knows this, I'd say something like "You know that's the same story, don't you?"

Comment: Some people habitually insert meaningless filler words into their conversation, mostly to cover pauses. "You know" is one such filler. Um and ahh are others. I hypothesis that a learner of English, who was in frequent contact with such a person, might become confused about the usage of "you know".