# Should I use 'no' or 'know'?

Tags: word-choice, grammar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it “that's the same story, know?” or “that's the same story, no?”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11887/is-it-thats-the-same-story-know-or-thats-the-same-story-no)

Which word should I use in this sentence, *no* or *know*?

> you also same college no?

> you also same college know?

Comment: @Martha nice edits.  I probably wouldn't have answered the original, even if I could parse it

Comment: Related (Possible duplicate?): [Is it "That's the same story, know" or "That's the same story, no"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11887/is-it-thats-the-same-story-know-or-thats-the-same-story-no)

Comment: @Tragicomic - same asker, actually...

Comment: @Dusty, and *that* is tragicomic :)

Answer (score 4):

Neither of those sentences are valid English, but to answer your question, when you want to confirm something you've said is correct *no* is a valid option while *know* is not.  In a bit better English:

> You also attend the same college, no?

I believe this usage of *no* is more a carry over from other languages, however, especially romantic languages.  A native speaker would likely prefer using *right*

> You also attend the same college, right?

Comment: Or "..., didn't you?"

Comment: @psmears: "..., don't you"? It's in present tense, isn't it?

Comment: @CesarGon: Yes, sorry, I misread "attend" as "attended"... it's still very early in my timezone :)

Comment: Even in French, one says *n'est-ce pas?*

Comment: @psmears: ;-) ...